# Sending multiple JSON data in HTTP2 from client to server in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http2, nodejs-stream

I have a working http2 server and client where I am sending a JSON data from client to server using POST method. As http2 in Node.js has duplex stream, I read the data from server stream using events 'data' and 'end'. Now I want to send the same data multiple times. But how do I differentiate new data from old data?

I want to do this using sleep ,because (correct me if I am wrong) when we send many many packets from clients to server it will eventually eat up all my CPU resource. Now how will the stream events in server behave when they don't receive data (I mean 'data' and 'end') , and how will I use them again to get data? Assume that when server receive data it stores it in a file.

Server:

```js
const h2=require('http2');
const fs=require('fs');
const options={
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
//server begin
const server=h2.createSecureServer(options);
server.on('error', (err)=>{throw err});

server.on('stream', (stream, headers)=>{        
    stream.respond({':status': 200})        //giving out response headers
    if(headers[':method']==='POST'){
        let data=''     
        let i=0;   
        stream.on('data',(chunk)=>{
            console.log(`iteration: ${++i}`)
            data+=chunk
        });
        stream.on('end', ()=>{
            // stream.close()      
            console.log('\n')
            console.log(JSON.parse(data))
        })
    }else if(headers[':method']==='GET'){
        stream.end('Hello from SMF')
    }else{
        //else condition
    }
})
server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
//server end
```

Client:

```js
const h2=require('http2');
const fs=require('fs');
const packet=require('./packet.json');

//client start
const client=h2.connect('https://localhost:3000',{      //establishing connection
    ca: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
});
client.on('error', (err)=>{throw err})

const req=client.request({              //giving out a post request
    ':method': 'POST',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
})
req.setEncoding('utf8');
req.on('error', (err)=>{throw err})

// req.write(JSON.stringify(packet))


req.end(JSON.stringify(packet), ()=>{   //writing the data to SMF
    req.on('response', (headers)=>{     //getting the response headers
        if(headers[':status']===200) console.log('success')
        req.close()                     //closing client stream
        client.close()                  //closing client session
    })
})
//client end
```

JSON data:

```js
{
  "supi": "imsi-<IMSI>",
  "pduSessionId": 235,
  "dnn": "<DNN>",
  "sNssai": {
    "sst": 0
  },
  "servingNfId": "<AMF Identifier>",
  "n1SmMsg": {
    "contentId": "n1msg"
  },
  "anType": "3GPP_ACCESS",
  "smContextStatusUri": "<URI>"
}
```

(I know that I have used secure server, you can just remove certificates from code and use createServer() instead).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using TimeInterval in javascript...

```js
i=0;
let timer=setInterval(()=>{
    i++;
    req.write(JSON.stringify(packet));          //sending request packet
    if(i==5){                                   //no of packets
        req.end(()=>{
             req.close();
             client.close();
        })
        clearInterval(timer);
    } 
}, 10)                                          //time interval
```

I was able to send multiple files using this

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you use the `drain` event you should be able to avoid ever running out of memory and crashing. Here are the docs for that: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain